# Convert div to span with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a few `div`s which makes a little bit too spacey between the footer and the body. So i want to convert one div to a span. But when I do that, it messes the footer's content a bit up.

How can i do this and keep the styles that already have been defined for the footer?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

```
div.footer {
width: 986px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom:18px;
border: 0;
text-align: left;
color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML and CSS so we can help you out more? Or a live example would be great.

Comment: Eh... you sure converting a `div` element to a `span` element will solve your problem? It's not one of the usual methods to ironing out CSS positioning quirks

Comment: Yes, because there are 2 divs next to eachother which creates a hugh gap between the body and the footer. With span this gap can be reduced. @Kyle Sevenoaks, it's kind of big and there is no live example atm.

Comment: This solution will more than likely cause more problems that it solves, maybe you have a problem with margins, it would help us alot if you posted the relevant code and/or a live example. You can use www.jsFiddle.net for a temp live example :)

Comment: i added the relevant css of the footer, does this help?

Comment: Yes, but we need more, to see how each element interacts with each other.

Comment: You didn't ask the right question, you want to solve this problem: "there are 2 divs next to eachother which creates a hugh gap between the body and the footer". So there is a gap between the content and the footer div, might be some padding, margin, but converting to span won't solve this. You should post the HTML code containing the two divs, and the CSS you tried to apply. As Kyle said you can post it jsfiddle, if you want.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you already know, the difference between a `<div>` and a `<span>` is just that one defaults to `display:block;` and the other to `display:inline;`. To make one act as the other, just set the display style to the other type.

However, you already said you tried this and it didn't achieve the effect you were looking for. There is another display property, which is less well known, but provides a half-way house between the two:

```
display:inline-block;
```

What it does is display it inline, but still with block-like properties. (This is basically how an `<img>` tag works by default).

Could this be the answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

To convert a div to a span, simply add:

```
.myDiv
{
   display: inline;
}
```

But I'm really not sure that this is the solution you're after.

Comment: I tried that, but it didnt work. its not taking all those other styles with it. it just align's to the left.

Comment: Because it is now an inline element, like we said, this converting a div to a span isn't the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

**Quote:**

> *there are 2 divs next to eachother which creates a hugh gap between the body and the footerbody and the footer*

**Solutions:**

- Remove empty div(s) from HTML
- Remove empty div(s) by adding `display:none`
- Reduce `height` of the div(s)
- Reduce `margin` or `padding` of the div(s)
- Set `position:relative; top:-[yourownnumber]px` to `.footer`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow:auto;` to your span. Also add `display:block;`

Comment: This is the reverse of what the op asked.

Comment: No it's not, the SPAN element most of the times need some extra attributes to start behaving as a block object and not 'fall' over the underlying DIV.

Comment: "So i want to convert one div to a span." You posted how to convert a span to a div :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is too much space between the footer and the body, have you looked at what the margins and paddings are on the affected divs?  Does something have a height or a min-height that is making some of the content within the body taller than the natural end of the content?  Firebug is a great tool for this.

Div is a block element.  Other block elements are paragraphs, headings, lists, etc.  Span is an inline element. Other inline elements are strong, image, anchor, etc.
You still need the body to be contained in a block-level element.

Answer (score -1):

How if add this:

```
position:relative /*optional*/
float:left;
left:0px;
```

I always do this before i know to use span when I first learn css I always do  to my element content.